# Db checks and concurrent transactions

Tags: sql, transactions, acid

How do dbms guarantee that the checks\comstraints we define are always true after commit ?

I mean they might use special technique because just executing the checks just before commit, like we can do, just wouldn't work because of multiple transaction going on at the same time ?

Does Acid properties guarantee us that the db state will always be consistent no matter how  many transaction are running in parallel ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Different databases use different techniques, but basically, all end-up ***locking*** something to make sure things that *cannot* be changed to make sure the `CONSTRAINT` is kept are not actually changed.

From [programmerinterview.com](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/database-sql/database-locking/):

> **What is a database lock in the context of SQL? Provide an example and explanation.**
>
> A database lock is used to “lock” some data in a database so that only one database user/session may update that particular data. So, database locks exist to prevent two or more database users from updating the same exact piece of data at the same exact time. When data is locked, then that means that another database session can NOT update that data until the lock is released (which unlocks the data and allows other database users to update that data. Locks are usually released by either a ROLLBACK or COMMIT SQL statement.

---

This means that if you `INSERT` a row in table `a` that has a `FOREIGN KEY` constrainto to table `b`, the corresponding row in table `b` will be *locked* until the end of your transaction, so that it cannot be deleted by another concurrent transaction until you finish yours.

Some other different techniques might be used by Multi-Version Concurrency Control databases; but they're based in the same principle.